# What's the best way to "discover" a header row when parsing inconsistent data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pretty terrible client that seems incapable of consistently formatting the excel files they send over for input.

Unfortunately, they also pay well, so my pleas of rejecting this data have fallen on deaf ears.

The problem:

Every week, we receive an excel file. One of the sheets is the one we want. At SOME row, it starts being a usable table. Based on how the client feels, this could be row 2 or row 920. I've already written the post-formatting pandas code. Here's what I got to work, but I hate it so much:

```
IDENTIFER = 'nunya_business'
SHEETNAME = 'nunya_business_2'
CSVNAME = 'nunya_business_3'
FILENAME = 'nunya_business_4'

df = pd.read_excel(FILENAME, SHEETNAME)
df.to_csv(CSVNAME, index=False)

list_of_data = []

with open(CSVNAME) as openfile:
    reader = csv.reader(openfile)
    good_to_go = False
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == IDENTIFIER:
            good_to_go = True
        if not good_to_go:
            continue
        list_of_data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_data)
my_actual_func(df)
```

I don't mind writing verbose code but it just feels annoying. Any intelligent way to do this?

Comment: what would be the content before the usable table? empty?

Comment: It is usually! I'm not going to assume its empty when I ship obviously but happy to hear a solution that starts me off

Comment: "itertools.dropwhile" could make the code a bit shorter.

Comment: @butscher that is exactly the pythonic solution I wanted, if you write it out as an answer I'll happily accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `itertools.dropwhile` the code to build `list_of_data` can be reduced to (untested):

```
from itertools import dropwhile

...

with open(CSVNAME) as openfile:
    list_of_data = list(dropwhile(lambda row: row[0] != IDENTIFIER, csv.reader(openfile)))
```